# Get Sum for Unique ids ONLY Excel Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table that looks like this.

```
    Code    ID  Rate
    AAA     
    BBB     
    CCC     2   0.307
    DDD     7   0.106
    EEE     
    FFF     3   0.524
    GGG     3   0.524
    HHH     3   0.524
    III     
    JJJ     
    KKK     1   0.344
    LLL     1   0.344
```

The "Rate" is always the same for the "ID".

I want to get the rate for each unique ID in the list and total it up using a formula.

Is it possible to just get the total from the above table or am I going to need a helper column like this?

```
Code    ID  Rate    Unique Rate
AAA         
BBB         
CCC     2   0.307   0.307
DDD     7   0.106   0.106
EEE         
FFF     3   0.524   0.524
GGG     3   0.524   
HHH     3   0.524   
III         
JJJ         
KKK     1   0.344   0.344
LLL     1   0.344
```

Ideally, I want to just be able to past in codes in and have it give me a total. Currently I have V-look ups in the "ID" and "Rate" Column.

```
Code    ID  Rate    Total
AAA                 1.281
BBB         
CCC     2   0.307   
DDD     7   0.106   
EEE         
FFF     3   0.524   
GGG     3   0.524   
HHH     3   0.524   
III         
JJJ         
KKK     1   0.344   
LLL     1   0.344
```

This worked for me!

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(IF(B2:B13<>"",C2:C13/COUNTIFS(B2:B13,B2:B13&"")))}
```

Comment: Query your table, choose the rate column and remove duplicates. Then close and apply. Then add a total to the bottom of the query table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C2:C13/COUNTIFS(B2:B13,B2:B13&""))
```

[image]

Comment: I had to make it an array formula because of my look ups I am guessing but it works like this now. In edit Thank you!